# Find the norm of $p(A)x$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

> Let , $A$ be a $n\times n$ self adjoint matrix with eigen values $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\cdots ,\lambda_n$. Let , $\displaystyle \|x\|=\sqrt{|x_1|^2+\cdots |x_n|^2}$ for $x=(x_1,\cdots ,x_n)\in \Bbb C^n$. If $p(A)=a_0I+a_1A+\cdots +a_nA^n$. Then the value of $\displaystyle \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|p(A)x\|$ is :
>
> $1. \max \{a_0+a_1 \lambda_j+\cdots+a_n \lambda_j^n:1\le j\le n\}$.
>
> $2. \max \{|a_0+a_1 \lambda_j+\cdots+a_n \lambda_j^n|:1\le j\le n\}$.
>
> $3. \min \{a_0+a_1 \lambda_j+\cdots+a_n \lambda_j^n:1\le j\le n\}$.
>
> $4. \min \{|a_0+a_1 \lambda_j+\cdots+a_n \lambda_j^n|:1\le j\le n\}$

We have $\displaystyle \|p(A)x\|^2=\|a_0x+a_1A(x)+a_2A^2(x)+\cdots +a_nA^n(x)\|^2\le |a_0|^2|x|^2+|a_1|^2|A(x)|^2+\cdots +|a_n|^2|A^n(x)|^2$

Then how I can proceed further  and where I use the condition that "$A$ is self adjoint" ?

Comment: The last equality is false. Vectors $x, Ax, A^2x, \ldots$ are not necessary orthogonal. Regarding the problem: since $A$ is self-adjoint there is an orthogonal basis in $\mathbb{C}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. Pass to the coordinates corresponding to this basis and be happy.

Comment: I got my fallacy... But not getting your answer how to solve ?

Comment: Do you know that a self-adjoin matrix has an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors?

Comment: @PetrNaryshkin Actually I don't know that. If I assume first that it is true then what's the next step?

Comment: @PetrNaryshkin I have edited my actual question. Please have a look on it.

Comment: So, what do you know about them? This is important here because the problem actually follows instantly from Spectral Theorem and the fact about basis is a weaker version. The answer in number 2, btw.

Comment: Yeah.. I know the answer..but how to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67148/discussion-between-petr-naryshkin-and-topo).

Answer (score 1):

A key fact about selfadjoint matrices:

> Eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal

Using this repeatedly, one quickly shows that $A$ admits an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. Let $V$ be the unitary that makes the change of basis from the canonical basis to $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$. The key observation is that the set of all $x$ such that $\|x\|=1$ is the same as the set of all $x$ such that $\|Vx\|=1$. So we may assume that  $x=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\,v_j$.

Then any $x$ can be written 
$$
x=\sum_{j=1}^n x_jv_j,
$$
and
$$\tag{1}
p(A)x=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\,p(A)v_j
$$
It is easy to check that 
$$\tag{2}
p(A)v_j=p(\lambda_j)v_j.
$$
So 
$$
p(A)x=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\,p(\lambda_j)v_j,
$$
and, since $\sum_{j=1}^n|x_j|^2=1$,
$$
\|p(A)x\|=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n |x_jp(\lambda_j)|^2\right)^{1/2}\leq\max\{|p(\lambda_j)|:\ 1\leq j\leq n\}.
$$
The equality can be achieved by making a particular $x_j=1$ and the rest zero.

Comment: I did not understand how you wrote last inequality

Comment: If $|p(\lambda_j)|≤ c$ for all $j$, then$$\sum_j|x_j|^2|p(\lambda_j)|^2\leq c^2\sum_j|x_j|^2=c^2.$$